# IE11 does not send cookies to server after opening a new window from a nested frameset

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, internet-explorer-11

**Summary**: A client has a problem when launching a new browser window using IE11, where no cookies are sent to the new window. I am unable to reproduce the problem locally. It will work if they use FireFox or a different LMS.

**Detail**: The client is running a LMS and imports a SCORM package from us which opens a frameset to our site - note the clients LMS and our content are on different domains. 
As part of the content the user clicks on a link and a new window is opened using window.open(url, "_blank"...) or an anchor tag with a _blank target, the url is always on the same domain as the page that launched it. 
When the new window is opened no cookies from the previous page are sent.

I can see that additional requests on the previous page maintain the cookies and new cookies set within the new window are sent back and forth.

If the client uses FireFox to launch the LMS or if the client launches the content from ScormCloud within IE the problem does not occur and the new window launches with all cookies intact.

I have attempted to replicate their environment locally (same OS, IE and configuration settings) but I am unable to reproduce the problem, or work out how to work around the problem.

Any ideas on what the problem may be, how to reproduce it or even work around it?